# Agrupación campo único

Tags: sql, agrupación

Tengo los datos Nombre: A, B; Numero; 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6. Hago un

```
SELECT nombre, numero 
FROM tabla
```

y se muestran 3 registros para cada nombre: 
A-1, A-2, A-3, B-4, B-5, B-6. Querría que se agruparan los nombres, mostrando solo el nombre en la primera fila y el resto en blanco. Pero si hago un SELECT nombre, numero FROM tabla GROUP BY nombre, da un error indicando que para cada nombre hay más de un campo asociado

```
 nombre | número
 ----------------
 A      | 1
        | 2
        | 3 
 B      | 4
        | 5
        | 6
```

¿Sabrían cómo puedo agrupar campos, mostrando solo el contenido del primero y sin omitir filas? Como se muestra en la columna "nombre".

Gracias

Comment: Lo quieres todo en una sola linea entiendo? Que es lo que has intentado para que no te salga? Comparte tu código

Comment: No se ha mostrado el formato que he hecho. Mis disculpas, es la primera vez que uso el foro. Tengo los datos Nombre: A, B; Numero; 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.  Hago un "SELECT nombre, numero   FROM tabla" y se muestran 3 registros para cada nombre: A-1, A-2, A-3, B-4, B-5, B-6. Querría que se agruparan los nombres, mostrando solo el nombre en la primera fila y el resto en blanco. Pero si hago un SELECT nombre, numero FROM tabla GROUP BY nombre, da un error indicando que para cada nombre hay más de un campo asociado.

Comment: Entiendo que lo que quieres es que te salgan dos filas, en la primera que te salga `A -> 1, 2, 3` y la segunda `B -> 1, 2, 3`. del tipo `nombre -> numeros`

Comment: ¿Y que motor de base de datos estas usando?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que buscas es la función `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Teniendo una tabla de la siguiente manera:

```
 -------
| A - 1 |
 -------
| A - 2 |
 -------
| A - 3 | 
 -------
| B - 4 |
 -------
| B - 5 |
 -------
| B - 6 |
 -------
```

Si lo que quieres es agrupar las letras en una misma fila y que en la columna de números se muestren agrupados todos en la misma columna tienes que usar el GROUP_CONCAT de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT nombre, GROUP_CONCAT(numero) FROM tabla GROUP BY nombre;

output:
 -------------
| A - 1, 2, 3 |
 -------------
| B - 4, 5, 6 |
 -------------
```

Comment: David esta clausula es propia de SQL genérico o de algun implementación?

Comment: Es sólo para mysql. Con un poco de suerte es la bbdd que está usando...

Comment: Perdón, estoy usando SQL genérico.

Comment: @Rift que es SQL generico? podes aclararlo en tu pregunta? vos queres que se vea asi el resultado?